# Is it possible to use UdpClient through an anonymous proxy?

Tags: vb.net, udp, proxies

I am sending a big endian byte array to a UDP host and all works well, but I need to incorporate proxies into the mix.

From what I've found (or haven't found) there is no straight forward way to use anonymous proxies (or even Socks4/5) with UdpClient. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Proxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for the proxy. Check the MSDN code snippet link for more information. I had a similar problem and this helped.